# Did I get this randrange() range correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm trying to get this homework done I've completed almost all of it besides formatting to make it look readable and this little problem I've been having, I can't seem to be getting this `randrange()` to work properly. It works most of the time, but every so often I get the error at the bottom.

```
dict_of_strings = {
    1:"PoopyPants",     #my go-to programming word... i donno what to tell you...
    2:"SleighBells",    #i asked my girlfriend or the next two
    3:"CookieMonster",
    4:"bomb",           #i have noidea how this one came to me
    5:"Blellow",        #when you mix blue and yellow, according to reece from Malcom in the Middle
    6:"RandomWordOne",  #because, random
    7:"Flaccid",        #theres a pattern to this word
    8:"Solid",          #maybe this is the pattern
    9:"VaultOneHundredEleven",  #FALLOUT4 HYPETRAIN
    10:"SirDoctorMcFlippertonTheTwentySecondOfTheHouseOfLordProfessorSteveWilkerton"    #this was a fun, convoluted phrase to come up with
}

def choice_is_rand(dict_of_strings):
    rand_word = str(dict_of_strings[random.randrange(0,10)]) #did i get this range correctly? i've always had trouble. I thought I had it, but i guess not...

    rand_backward = rand_word[::-1]

    print(rand_word)
    print(rand_backward.lower())
```

I'm trying to get the rand_word randrange to work, but I seem to be getting it wrong. My particular error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\User\My Documents\Komodo Projects\COP 1000\Module 11\Reverse the Word.py", line 116, in <module>
    main()
  File "I:\User\My Documents\Komodo Projects\COP 1000\Module 11\Reverse the Word.py", line 35, in main
    choice_is_rand(dict_of_strings)
  File "I:\User\My Documents\Komodo Projects\COP 1000\Module 11\Reverse the Word.py", line 73, in choice_is_rand
    rand_word = str(dict_of_strings[random.randrange(0,10)])
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: how about reading the doc or trying? would take less time than posting on SO... answer is "depends what you want to do".

Comment: @Pynchia ! Thank you! that seems to work, tested it about 20 times and seems to hold!

Could you explain why my method didn't work and why yours does?

Comment: If you have discrete *choices* then why would you use `randrange()`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is right: if your keys started from zero, you could just do `rand_word = random.choice(dict_of_strings)`

Comment: @ignacioVazquez-Abrams I wanted to randomize the choices

Comment: @pynchia Could you explain the how that works? I'm still getting my footing on Python

Comment: Then why wouldn't you use the function that takes *choices*?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: @F.Borges please see the thread of comments under Chrisitan Witts' answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
rand_word = str(dict_of_strings[random.randrange(0,10)])
```

Use this:

```
rand_word = str(dict_of_strings[random.randint(1, len(dict_of_strings))])
```

Two reasons:

- Your keys start at 1 and `randrange()` does not include the endpoint, while `randint()` does, so starting at 0 causes an error about 10% of the time for you.
- Getting the endpoint with `len(dict_of_strings)` means you can use different dicts.

However, `random.choice(dict_of_strings)` is more appropriate.

Comment: Ended up using, `random.choice(dict_of_strings)` but I'm going to keep this post in the back of my mind when I use random again.

Comment: @F.Borges Can I recommend starting your keys w/ `0` instead of `1`? It will help you avoid problems, since everything in Python uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: If you're going to use sequential ordering starting at 0 then perhaps a dict isn't the structure you're looking for in the first place.

Comment: Yes, might as well just use a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can either change your range choice to start at your first value, being `1`, or you can directly pick out the word with `choice`

```
# Select the word directly
random_word = random.choice(list(dict_of_strings.values()))
# Or select the key, and then access the word
random_word_index = random.choice(list(dict_of_strings.keys()))
random_word = dict_of_strings[random_word_index]

# As Pynchia pointed out, you can simply do the following without the
# need to fetch the keys, and cast them to a list.
# This will work on Python 3.5+, but not Python 3.4< or Python 2.7<
# in such case, you must make your keys start from zero, not one
random_word = random.choice(dict_of_strings)
```

Comment: upvoted. Note:  if the keys started from zero, it could just be `rand_word = random.choice(dict_of_strings)`

Comment: `random.choice(dict_of_strings)` works with keys starting from `1` like the OP has. Updated my post to reflect the simpler alternative.

Comment: uhm.. no it doesn't: you get a traceback with `KeyError: 0` (on python 3.4.3). I presume `choice` simply chooses a random element from the first index (zero), to the last (len-1), but this seq is a dictionary and the zero key does not exist

Comment: Must have been fixed in Python 3.5 then, as I was getting that exception on 2.7, but not 3.5, and assumed it was a 3.x improvement all round.

Comment: alright! I am going to update then! :) It may be worth mentioning/updating the answer then, to simplify and avoid using `.items` and `list`

Comment: I edited it to note that it won't work on 3.4< and 2.7< but does work on 3.5+. Cheers.

Comment: OK, I've edited it, since with keys starting from zero it can still work :)